# Как в js сделать эмуляцию клика по input?

Tags: javascript

Друзья! Есть такой вот инпут

```
<form onload="sendmail()" name='MainForm' method=POST>
    <textarea name="order_comment" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
    <input  type="submit" id="sssss" name="submit"  value="клик">
</form>
```

можно ли как то сделать эмуляцию клика без участия пользователя?

Comment: Вам нужно сымитировать клик или отправить форму? Если второе, то у формы есть метод `submit()`

Comment: желательно второе

Comment: Так я написал как

Comment: @AntonShchyrov пытаюсь делать так - document.forms.['MainForm'].submit()  форма не реагирует

Comment: что такой `MainForm`? Покажите html

Comment: @AntonShchyrov это name формы

Comment: Может быть, `document.forms['MainForm'].submit()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вместо стандартного метода `submit` вы получаете элемент с кнопкой (по её имени):

```
document.forms['MainForm'].submit
// <input type="submit" id="sssss" name="submit" value="клик">
```

Должно помочь:

```
document.forms['MainForm'].submit.click()
```

Либо удалите у кнопки атрибут `name="submit"` и будет можно вызывать отправку формы через `submit`.

```
document.forms['MainForm'].submit()
```

Comment: Никакие из методов не помогли. у этой формы нет action, куда имено отправляется она я не могу понять, т.к. этой очень старый движок shopscript. Экшена нет, а форма каким то образом обрабатывается. Может дело в этом?

Comment: @sbaikov если экшена нет, то запрос отправляется на эту же страницу (только методом `POST`). Либо обрабатывается на клиенте через `js`.